# Split buttons with bootstrap 4 won't display properly

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have multiple issues with bootstrap4 and split button.

I am trying to create a “multi-purpose” button one action at the time but user can change the action with a dropdown menu. So split button seems a good choice.

But I have some trouble to use it.

First the dropdown arrow I smaller than aside button I don’t understand why because I just copy/paste example from bootstrap or w3schools (I inspect their page and it is the same code).
Second issue when I click and dropdown menu button move it seems that css apply on “show” class “display: block” while on “btn-group” class is “inline-block”. I don’t understand why on my html page this have effect while on bootstrap or w3schools there is no change.
Finally the last one … dropdown list don’t display items as a list. I see on several website that we can use  to solve this issue but I am perplexed because on documentation they don’t talk about it. It must have something I do wrong.

Below a simplified html page with my issues

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test btn</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row m-5 pb-5">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-5 pb-5">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row m-5 pb-5">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            </div>
          </div>
          <button id="injAllInc">Inj/Extr tous les incidents</button><button id="injAllTp">Inj/Extr tous les TPs</button><button id="injSelec">Inj/Extr selection</button>
          <!-- Example split danger button -->
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group dropup">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
              Split dropup
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--SCRIPT-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-zDnhMsjVZfS3hiP7oCBRmfjkQC4fzxVxFhBx8Hkz2aZX8gEvA/jsP3eXRCvzTofP" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

thanks you for helping me

please forgive my aproximate English I am French

best regards

Answer (score 1):

So the fault is you ware using `bootstrap-3`'s `css` and `bootstrap-4`'s `js` together. either use `bootstrap-3` or use `bootstrap-4`.
Here is the solution using `bootstrap-4`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test btn</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row m-5 pb-5">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-5 pb-5">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row m-5 pb-5">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            </div>
          </div>
          <button id="injAllInc">Inj/Extr tous les incidents</button><button id="injAllTp">Inj/Extr tous les TPs</button><button id="injSelec">Inj/Extr selection</button>
          <!-- Example split danger button -->
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group dropup">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
              Split dropup
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--SCRIPT-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```